# Hosting SpringBoot on Tomcat 9 gives 404 error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat9

I'm trying to host an APP developed by the EU ([ESPD Git](https://github.com/ESPD/ESPD-Service)) on my local Tomcat 9 server running on JAVA 8 JDK. I have just basic expririence with Java and this creates me a lot of problems.

When I run the project with the command:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Xms768m -Xmx768m -Dserver.port=8080 -jar espd-web.war
```

The app is running smooth, but when I try to run it on a Tomcat 9, and then go to the Tomcat Manager and click on the context path "/espd" I got 404 error. 
The log file are not of any help as they only log that an 404 error occurs and nothing more.

I build the *.war file with both profiles defined in the project.

```
mvn package -Pembedded
```

and with

```
mvn package -Pnon-embedded
```

But non of them is working in Tomcat. As my understending goes the project is build on Springboot framework.

Hope someone can help me and point me in the right direction.

In the project requirements it states that Tomcat 7 and Java 7 should be used. Tried that also, but still not working.

Comment: when you run the build with -Pnon-embedded, is the war name "espd-web.war" also ?

Comment: yes, i got the same file name on both profiles

Comment: then your application context-path should be "/espd-web" by default instead of "/espd", if that is the problem I can help you to use "/espd" as context -path without renaming the war file

Comment: Did you set  application.properties
# Context path of the application
server.context-path=/espd

Comment: Or try renaming the war file to espd.war

Comment: Tried the rename before. Didnt work also. Added the context path to application.properties but also not working.

Comment: Adding the context path to application.properties only works for embedded servers

Answer (score -1):

tomcat server already started without anything in it, i.e. no web applications. You have to 'run' or actually deploy something in that Eclipse Tomcat server so you won't get the 404s.

The fact that you do get 404 error messages indicates that Tomcat actually running. If you shut it down from Eclipse/IJ/TaskManager, you won't get those 404's anymore

Comment: where is the eclipse tomcat server? I tried to shutdown different procesess but then I get "Can't reach site". Because no server is running.